# How to increment day in loop PHP

Tags: php, loops, date

I have the following code

I get a date begin and date end

```
$dateBegin = date('2019-11-15');
$dateEnd = date('2019-11-20'); 
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
   ...
}

//output
2019-11-15 - 2019-11-20
2019-11-21 - 2019-11-26
2019-11-27 - 2019-11-32
2019-11-33 - 2019-11-38
2019-11-39 - 2019-11-44
```

how to implement a loop add 5 days between begin and end day ?

Comment: $date = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime("2007-02-28"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strtotime()`.

Note that I had to use 6 days to get your desired outcome, not 5.

```
<?php

$dateBegin = date('2019-11-15');
$dateEnd = date('2019-11-20'); 
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
     echo "{$dateBegin} - {$dateEnd}\r\n";

     $dateBegin =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateBegin. ' + 6 days'));
     $dateEnd =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateEnd. ' + 6 days'));

}
```

Comment: thanks, that was exactly what I needed